# Dynamic get string from AppLocalizations.of(context) in flutter

Tags: flutter

How do I do

```
AppLocalizations.of(context)[variable]
```

I get the error

> The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'AppLocalizations'.

I know I can create a new map and use it but is there any other way.